# Updating a Bool on load in coredata

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, swift3

I'm trying to check to see if the app has already been installed and if so, delete all pending local notifications. I'm trying to use this code, but it doesn't seem to be saving correctly to my Core Data.

```
// check to see if the app has already been installed

    let global = Global(context:coreDataStack.managedContext)

    print("Has the app been installed before = \(global.wasLoaded)") // returns false

    if(global.wasLoaded == false){

        print("remove local notifications")
        // remove all notifications
        center.removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()

        global.wasLoaded = true
        coreDataStack.saveContext()
        print("Has the app been installed before = \(global.wasLoaded)") // returns true
    }
```

The next time I run the app, the wasLoad bool comes back as false still.
Do I have run a fetch request here to make this work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you're making a new `Global` managed object, so it always has the default value. To achieve what you want, you'd have to fetch the already set `Global` managed object and check it's properties.

Core Data is a very heavy solution to this problem, a better one would be to use `UserDefualts` like this:

```
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isFirstLaunch") == false {
        // Perform first launch actions

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isFirstLaunch")
    }

    // Continue with regular setup
```

You compare to `false` because `bool(forKey:)` returns `false` if the value was never set for a given key.

Comment: Thanks jjatie, and I know core data is over kill for this, the rest of the app is already using core data so I thought I was just add an entity to the list and keep track of it that way. I assumed I was missing the request, but just couldn't remember the details on that.

Comment: In that case, there are many questions on SO already related to Core Data fetching. I encourage you to check those out. Still, this is a much slower solution than simply using `UserDefaults`.

Comment: for your solution would I then set isFirstLaunch = true after the first launch actions were preformed?